# Bindview not working in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, butterknife

I have downloaded a project from github, and I try to use eclipse to modify it. This project imports butterknife and uses bindview, but after I imported butterknife, it still reminds me that "**the import butterknife.BindView cannot be resolved**", and "**BindView cannot be resolved to a type**". Can someone help me please?

ps. I also wish I could use Android Studio, but there is something wrong with it. I am in China and even though I use VPN, it still tells me that "could not HEAD ". So please tell me how to fix this in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve this problem by adding butterknife-annotations.jar. It is truely hard to run android studio project using eclipse, I hope I can use Android Studio someday.

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-implementationr:8.5.1'

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have solved this problem, although I have encountered another...I couldn't find butterknife-implementationr, is that butterknife-compiler. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: u wlc @SiriusSong